# how to add a delay on a form_tag ruby on rails with remote:true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

code is making the request after i type anything, and because of the time each requisition takes to load, this is breaking the code. How can i add a delay to fix it?

html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag search_by_name_contacts_path, remote: true, method:'get', class: 'w-100' do %>
    <div class=row>
        <div class="col-auto pr-0">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </div>
        <div class=col>
            <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Pesquisar" id="search-contact-query" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :target, params[:target] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :requester, params[:requester] %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def search_by_name
    @contacts = Contact.filter_by_modal(params, current_company, current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.json { render json: @contacts.to_json(methods: [:abbr_name]) }
  end
end
```

Comment: If the form submits after typing, but you didn't press enter key, that means you have some Javascript submitting the form.

Comment: no, only submit after i type, but the firsts requisitions, have too many items to load and when it loads, i already typed more letters so is making more requests. and the firsts requests load after the last, because have more items to load.

Comment: Great. Then please show javascript you are using

Comment: no using javascript here, only ruby on rails

Comment: Please open developer tools in chrome, go to Network tab, type something in the input and check what shows us as Initiator. This is what's making the request.

Comment: doens't appear anything